# Undefined value to database using ajax when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi i have table i am performing an inline edit and i am trying to update value to database using clicking on the button(i.e:img),i tried with onclick function but its edit value,it shows
"`value=undefined&rowid=undefined&field=undefined"` ,

below is my code.can one one guide me how  to do that .thanks

**my ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('td.edit').click(function (e) {

            var $target = $(e.target);
            if ($target.is('#editbox')) {
                return;
            }
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

            $(this).addClass('ajax');
            $(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="5" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

            $('#editbox').select();
        }

    );

    $('td.edit1 img').on('click', function () {
        arr = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "clientnetworkpricelist/update.php",
            data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[1] + "&field=" + arr[2],
            success: function (data) {
                $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    });

});
```

**My Html**

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'fms';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'fms';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");


$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];
$region=$_GET['region'];
$clientid_query="";
$region_query="";

if($clientid!=""){
$clientid_query="WHERE clientid = '$clientid'";}
else{
    if($region!=""){
$region_query="WHERE region = '$region'";}
else{
    $region_query="";
        }    
}


$sql="SELECT * FROM clientnetworkprice"." ".$clientid_query or $region_query ;
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{    
if($alt == 1)
        {   echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }

echo '  <td  class=" '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["clientid"].'</td>
         <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientid" class=" '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>  
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_country" class=" '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_networkname" class=" '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["networkname"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mcc" input type="text" name="mcc" id="mcc" class=" '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td>  
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mnc" input type="text" name="mnc" id="mnc" class="'.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["mnc"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_mnp" class="edit mnp '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["mnp"].'</td>';


$ColumnNames = mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'clientnetworkprice' AND column_name NOT
IN ('id','clientid','region', 'country', 'networkname', 'mcc', 'mnc', 'mnp','clientprice','supplierroute'
)") or die("mysql error"); 
$columnArray=array();
$i=0;
while($rows1=mysql_fetch_array($ColumnNames))
{
$columnArray[]=$rows1[0];

echo '<td  id="CPH_GridView1_xxx" width="0px;" class="edit '.$columnArray[$i].' '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows[$columnArray[$i]].'</td>';   

$i++;
}    
 echo ' <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientprice" class="edit clientprice '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["clientprice"].'</td>
        <td id="CPH_GridView1_supplierroute" class="edit supplierroute '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["supplierroute"].'
                                </td>

        <td class="edit1"><img  src="/image/Picture1.png" style="margin:0 0 0 6px;;cursor:pointer" ></td>'
        ;

echo '</tr>';

}

?>
```

Comment: what is this $('.ajax input').val() giving you? I  can't see in your code the class "ajax"

Answer (score 0):

first of all ..

what you have is this

```
  <td id="CPH_GridView1_clientid" class=" '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>
```

you missed `>` for `<td>`

```
 <td id="CPH_GridView1_mcc"><input type="text" name="mcc" id="mcc" class=" '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td>    
                      ----^^^--- here
```

secondly all your values is undefined since your selector `$(this).parent().attr('class')`

```
$('td.edit1 img').on('click', function () {
    arr = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ');
    ....
```

**selects `td.edit1` element itself which doesnot have any other class than `edit1` so `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` is undefined. i think you meant `arr[0]`(first element which will give you edit1) and `.ajax input` is no where to be found in the document.. is that element there??**

Answer (score 0):

In your html, there is a space between "edit" and number(1) in "class", but in your jquery selector, you did not put any space between it, so it caused nothing to be found.  Thanks.